# EF Core SQLIte Unique Constraint Failed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I have this error with the following classes when attempting to perform a context.Add and Save.

> $exception  {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error
>   occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for
>   details. ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 19:
>   'UNIQUE constraint failed: Customer.Id'.

```
 public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SalesforceId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public State StateName { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Inspection> Inspections { get; set; }


    public WriteResult Create(Customer customer)
    {
        return CustomerService.CreateNewCustomer(customer);
    }
}
```

And

```
public class Inspection
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string SalesforceId { get; set; }
    public bool Synced { get; set; } 
    public bool Archived { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<InspectionItem> InspectionItems{ get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public WriteResult CreateInspection(Customer customer)
    {
        SalesforceId = customer.SalesforceId;
        CustomerId = customer.Id;
        Customer = customer;
        return InspectionService.CreateInspection(this);
    }

    public WriteResult CreateInspection()
    {
        return InspectionService.CreateInspection(this);
    }
```

And the writers

```
 public static WriteResult CreateInspection(Inspection inspection)
    {
        try
        {
            inspection.LastUpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            context.Inspections.Add(inspection);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return DataWrite.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception ez)
        {
            return WriteResult.ErrorOnWrite;
        }
    }

public static WriteResult CreateNewCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        try
        {
            if (context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SalesforceId == customer.SalesforceId) != null)
                return WriteResult.DuplicateKey;

            context.Customers.Add(customer);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return WriteResult.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return WriteResult.ErrorOnWrite;
        }
    }
```

There are 2 workflows, a user may or may not enter a customer. Regardless of that result a new inspection must be created at that time. Everything works fine when there is no customer associated with an inspection - they can both be created independently and just fine. The problem only occurs if the inspection has a reference to a customer. The desired relationship is a 1:M Customer:Inspection

I've tried nuking the DB, changing the customer object to a non-virtual, removing all customer properties (except for the navigation), re-reading a few MSDN articles on relationships and navigation and can not come up with a solve for this.

Anyone have any pointers on what i must be overlooking, entirely?

Here is the constraint

```
constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Survey", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Survey_Customer_CustomerId",
                    column: x => x.CustomerId,
                    principalTable: "Customer",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the inclusion of the navigation object into the model when I saved that caused the issue. Talk about a derp...

```
public WriteResult CreateInspection(Customer customer)
{
    SalesforceId = customer.SalesforceId;
    CustomerId = customer.Id;
    //Customer = customer;
    return InspectionService.CreateInspection(this);
}
```